# g++ giving errors where visual studio was happy - undefined reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, g++, cross-compiling

I have some code that runs fine on Visual Studio, and I am now trying to compile it on g++.  It is giving me 'undefined reference to SomeClass::someMethod() const' in a bunch of places.

Most commonly, it's the following situation:

```
for (const SomeListNode *node = owner->some_list; node != 0; node = node->getNext())
```

In this case, I get 'undefined reference to SomeListNode::getNext() const'.  This class's header file is explicitly included.  Why is this not legal in g++?

**edit for more info**

I am building with a makefile as such:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -DDEBUG -g
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp SomeList.cpp SomeListNode.cpp Location.cpp OutputControl.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=theprogram

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
```

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

The line of code originally listed is in the `OutputControl.cpp`.  It is taking a pointer to a `SomeListNode` and iterating over it.  `getNext`() returns a pointer to another `SomeListNode`.

It may also be of note that this is only occurring within static functions.

Comment: This looks like you implemented your own linked list. Are you sure you don't want to use `std::list` instead?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y You're right, although I'm going to be modifying it quite a bit and specializing it.  It's been a while since I've done C++, so I'm getting back into it in steps.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a list of involved .cpp files, and the compile/link commandline you use.

Comment: @Erik Sorry for the delay, I've added information

Comment: Just as an experiment, try moving OutputControl to the front of the file list. This *should not* affect anything though. Also, have you verified that SomeListNode actually implements the const `getNext()` member function and not just a non-const version?

Comment: That didn't change anything (as expected).  I have double checked that the method is implemented several times; I am sure it is.

Comment: Very odd revelation.  Within the makefile, this fails.  Typing in the g++ command by hand at command line compiles..

Comment: remove all your .o files and make again. You haven't setup dependencies, so there could be a stale old .o

Comment: Wow.  Thanks Erik.  What a stupid error

Answer (score 2):

You can only call const-qualified methods on a const-qualified object. If getNext() is not const, then you should use `SomeListNode *node` instead of `const SomeListNode *node`.

Comment: He gets a linker error, undefined reference, not the compiler error he'd get if a const member function was missing.

Comment: @socks: are you actually linking the object file where the `getNext` member function is defiend?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, yes.  This function is used elsewhere in other files as well and it has no issues there.  Unless the ordering in which I list the .cpp files matters?

Comment: @socks: are you compiling to static libs and linking them? Order does matter there.

Comment: @socks: Try putting the source file with that method after files that use it, then.

Comment: @PiotrLegnica I have tried this.  Would the method being static change anything?

Comment: @socks: Yeah, you cannot call static method as a non-static one.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined references are linker errors, and these are unrelated to header inclusions. You have to make sure that you have compiled the definitions of those functions into some object file, and that the object file is passed to the linker.

Beware that if you are compiling to static libraries, the order of the libraries in the linker command line affects the result. In particular, if a library depends on other libraries, the dependent should appear in the command line *before* all the depended on libs.

At any rate, compile each object file separately into a .o or a library and use nm to extract the list of symbols that is defined in each one of the translation units that should tell you whether the definition has been compiled or not and will help you determine the order if you are compiling static libs.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you set up dependencies in your makefile so that objects that depends on others are made in the correct order. Also setup a clean target that deletes .o files. After this run make clean, and make.

This is the best suggestion I can think of with the information you have given us.

Answer (score 0):

Pass all your .cpp files to the g++ compile command.

```
g++ -g -Wall -o myapp File1.cpp File2.cpp File3.cpp
```

EDIT:

If you're using static libraries, you should add these *last* on the g++ commandline.

The linker processes passed files in order, and when it encounters a static library it searches for symbols that are undefined *so far*. You can change this using `--whole-archive`

Comment: In one g++ invocation, or multiple?

Comment: In a single one, through a makefile

Comment: If you're using a lib, it needs to be *last* on the link commandline.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the `nm` tool to find out which symbols are involved in you situation. It may look like this:

```
// foo.h
class Foo{
    public:
        void bar();
};

// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
void Foo::bar()
{
}

// bar.cpp
#include "foo.h"
void baz()
{
    Foo f;
    f.bar();
}

> nm foo.o
00000000 T _ZN3Foo3barEv

> nm bar.o
00000000 T _Z3bazv
         U _ZN3Foo3barEv
         U __gxx_personality_v0
```

Here you can see, that bar.o uses an undefined `_ZN3Foo3barEv` symbol (and a `__gxx_personality_v0`, but this is a compiler detail), which is marked `U`. This symbol is defined in `foo.o`, wehre it is marked `T`. To get the c++ name form the mangled name, you can use `c++filt`.

```
> c++filt _ZN3Foo3barEv
Foo::bar()

> c++filt _Z3bazv
baz()
```

To debug your problem you inspect both your SomeList.o and OutputControl.o files and look for SomeListNode::getNext instances. There might be lots of output, so you might want to filter the output with `nm file.o | grep 'SomeListNode.*getNext'`. Every `U` marked `SomeListNode::getNext` symbol form your OutputControl.o file must have an **exact** match in your SomeList.o file.

**Edit**: Adjusted answer to the posted Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

One difference between Visual Studio and g++ is how they deal with templates.  In Visual Studio, if you define a function in a template, but you never use it anywhere, VS won't typecheck it or generate any code.  In g++ it will typecheck (and it'll give you errors if there are any problems in it).